# Why can I reference a member of an enum that is only forward declared

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, forward-declaration

For example, given the following:

```
// enum.h
enum class TestEnum: int {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
};
```

```
// function.h
enum class TestEnum: int;
int TestFunction(TestEnum te = TestEnum::THREE);
```

```
// function.cpp
#include "enum.h"
#include "function.h"

int TestFunction(TestEnum te) { 
    return 5;
}
```

In my eyes this should not compile because in function.h, with `TestEnum` only being forward declared, the compiler cannot know that `TestEnum::THREE` (which is used as a default argument for `TestFunction`) is a valid member of the enum. And yet it does.

If I forward declare a class, I cannot access its members, but with enums it seems I can. Why is that? And is this something "legal" as per the standard, or did it just happen to work because of the way the compilers I tried (clang and gcc) are implemented?

Comment: You never compile "function.h" by itself. The actual translation unit is "function.cpp", which includes "enum.h" as well.

Comment: You can't. Try swapping two `#include`s in your `function.cpp`. The former actually "spills" `TestEnum`'s declaration to `function.h` when they're included in that order.

Comment: `#include` basicaly means "copy and paste the content of this file here". When you copy and paste these files in this order, the definitions are correct. Change the order and it suddenly won't compile anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Header files are not compiled. Source files are.

Within your function.cpp file, you first include enum.h, which contains TestEnum, and then you include function.h.

From the compiler point of view, it copy paste the content of those header files on top of your source file, so you do have access to the scoped value of the enum when your compiler arrives on the function.cpp file.

However, this would not work if the order of inclusion was first function.h and finally enum.h because the compiler could not know the content (here the scoped value of the enum) of TestEnum. This is the same behavior when you fast forward a class and try to access its members.

Comment: Side note: I sometimes compile complex headers by themselves to test whether or not they are 100% complete and self-consistent.